# Wordpress admin page with progress bar

Tags: wordpress, progress-bar

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin to do a migration of data from a custom CMS.
Since the migration itself follows several steps and would take a while before being completed, I would like to have an admin page that would show the progress of backend script while it's importing the data.
I have read some articles online about such a communication between the backend and the client but there's nothing about the situation in which client and backend are inside the Wordpress framework (there are some constrains about setting the client properly).

Thank you,

Luca

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the progress of a PHP process live, you will have to have the PHP script that is running update the state of a post that can be read from JavaScript such Angular over fixed intervals.

I would have the PHP create a post and store the process state using JSON, and have Angular using post and interval update the admin view.